Deriving the transition density for hyperbolic Brownian motion via the Fokker-Planck equation on the half plane
Context:
Let $\mathbb{H}=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: y>0\}$ by the half-plane model for hyperbolic space. Equip it with the metric tensor
$$g(x,y) = y^{-2} I_{2\times 2},$$
which corresponds to the line element $ds^2 = y^{-2}(dx^2+dy^2)$. Recall that the infinitesimal generator of a Brownian motion on a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$ is given by half the Laplace-Beltrami operator on $M$. Thus, in this case for $M=\mathbb{H}$ and $g$ defined above
$$\mathscr{G} = \frac12 \Delta_{\mathbb{H}} = \frac12 y^2 \Delta.$$
This is self-adjoint in $L^2(\mathbb{H}, \nu)$ where $\nu(dxdy) = y^{-2} dxdy$, the hyperbolic "volume" measure on the half-plane. If you know your SDEs and infinitesimal generators, you can identify the SDE immediately for Hyperbolic BM:
$$dX = Y dB^1 \text{ and } dY = Y dB^2.$$
Problem:
The transition density function $p(t,x,y)$ must solve
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}=\frac12 y^2 \Delta p$$
and with IC
$$p(0,x,y)=\delta(x-x_0)\delta(y-y_0),$$
where $y_0>0$. This is the PDE I am trying to solve.
Some work:
Trying to solve it directly in Cartesian coordinates has not been fruitful. Perusing some literature, I found the geodesic polar coordinates to be more tractable. For reference, see the derivation in Rogers and Williams Volume 2 p. 213. The geodesic polar coordinates are
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 x(r, \theta) \\
 y(r, \theta) 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{\cosh (r)-\sin (\theta ) \sinh (r)}\begin{bmatrix}
 \cos (\theta ) \sinh (r)\\
 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Here $(x,y)\neq(0,1)$ is the point at Lobachevsky-Poincare distance $r>0$ along the geodesic passing through $(0,1)$ at the angle $\theta$. Using the transformation rule
$$\tilde{g}_{ij} = \frac{\partial u^a}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial u^b}{\partial x^j} g_{ab},$$
with $g = y^{-2} I$ from above, it follows that
$$g(r,\theta) = \tilde{g}(r,\theta) = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0\\
 0 & \sinh^2(r)
\end{bmatrix}$$
Thus, the "volume" measure is
$$\nu(drd\theta) = \sinh(r) dr d\theta$$
Now you can compute the Laplace-Beltrami operator for $\mathbb{H}$ in geodesic polar coordinates using your favorite formula. Mine is simply $\Delta_M f= (\nabla_g \cdot g^{-1})^T \nabla f + \langle g^{-1}, \nabla^2 f\rangle_F$ where $\nabla_g \cdot \vec{v}:=\nabla \cdot (\sqrt{\det g} \vec{v})/\sqrt{\det g}$ is the manifold-divergence, which we apply to matrices row-wise.
Running through the computations for $\frac12 \nabla_g \cdot g^{-1}$ and $g^{-1/2}$ shows that
$$dr = \frac12 \coth (r) dt + dW^1$$
$$d\theta = \operatorname{csch}(r) dW^2$$
Hence, the Laplace-Beltrami operator in geodesic polar coordinates is given by
$$\Delta_{\mathbb{H}} = \frac12 \coth(r) \frac{\partial p}{\partial r} +\frac12 \left(\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial r^2} + \operatorname{csch}^2(r) \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial \theta^2}\right).$$
Now this, doesn't look much easier, but since HBM is isotropic, is is not hard to show that $p(t,r,\theta)$ does not depend on $\theta$. Hence, we have the simpler PDE for $p(t,r)$ as
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = \frac12 \coth(r) \frac{\partial p}{\partial r} +\frac12 \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial r^2}$$
Applying separation of variables $p(t, r) = T(t) R(r)$ we obtain
$$\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)} =\frac{\mathscr{G}R(r)}{R(r)},$$
where
$$\mathscr{G}R:= \frac12 R'' + \frac12 \coth(r) R'.$$
Thus, there must be some constant $\lambda$ such that
$$T'+\lambda T=0 \text{ and } \mathscr{G}R =-\lambda R,$$
so
$$T(t) = c_\lambda e^{-\lambda t},$$
and $R$ is an eigenfunction of $-\mathscr{G}$. This is equivalent to $R$ solving the second-order ODE
$$R'' +\coth(r) R' +\lambda R = 0.$$
This can be put into Sturm-Liouville form by multiplying by $\sinh(r)$,
$$\frac{d}{dr} \left[\sinh (r) R'\right]+2\lambda\sinh(r) R  =0.$$
Let $x(r) = \cosh(r)$. By chain rule and multiplying by $-1$, it is not very difficult to see that we now have the ODE
$$(1-x^2) y'' -2x y' +\nu(\nu+1) y=0,$$
where $y(x)=R(\cosh^{-1}(x))$ and $-2\lambda = \nu(\nu+1)$. This is a Legrende differential equation, which is also a Sturm-Liouville problem:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[(1-x^2) y'\right]+\nu(\nu+1)y = 0$$
The solutions are
$$P_\nu(z) = \sideset{_2}{_1}{F}\left(-\nu, \nu+1; 1; \frac{1-z}{2} \right),$$
for $|1-z|<2$ and
$$Q_\nu(z) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi} \Gamma(\nu+1)}{2^{\nu+1} \Gamma(\nu+3/2)z^{\nu+1}}\sideset{_2}{_1}{F}\left(\frac{\nu+1}{2}, \frac{\nu+2}{2}; \nu+3/2; \frac{1}{z^2} \right)$$
for $|z|>1$. These are Legrende functions of the first and second kind with non-integer degree $\nu$, in general.
Now the operator $-\mathscr{G}$ is self-adjoint on $L^2(\mathbb{H}, \sinh (r) drd\theta)$ so the eigenvalues are real, and also positive, and the eigenfunctions associated to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal, but the spectrum is not necessarily discrete since $\mathbb{H}$ is not compact.
Where I am stuck:
On a compact manifold, we could prove the operator is a compact operator on a Hilbert space, and so has a discrete spectrum and then our solution would be something of the form like
$$p(t, r|0, r_0) = \sum_{n} a_n X_n(r) e^{-\lambda_n t}$$
and then we can obtain $a_n$ from the IC, etc, etc.
By analogy, I would wager that we integrate over the continuous spectra so that
we have something like
$$p(t,r) = \int a_\lambda X_\lambda (r) e^{-\lambda t} d\lambda$$
but I am just thinking formally.
Questions:

Can anyone help me finish this derivation? (and verify this work)
Can anyone give me a brief overview of eigenfunction expansions when the spectra is continuous (if this even makes any sense). If not an overview, a recommendation to a good textbook?

(I have some functional analysis books and PDE books I am going to consult, but sometimes it takes awhile to find what you're looking for in general theory books when it comes from a specific problem..., so that is why I am asking here for someone to just help finish this derivation).

You can find a self contained derivation here: The Heat Kernel on Hyperbolic Space with additional resources in the bibliography
